# How to create different variables names while in a loop in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, dictionary, for-loop, variables

I want my code to be cleaner. I am using thousands of files that are always in the same order and can't change the order of the columns in these files.

Here is the messy part of my code:

```vb
'...

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='BL-remove'!$L$23"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='BL-remove'!$A$24:$A$4523"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='BL-remove'!$L$24:$L$4523"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph 2").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='BL-remove'!$K$23"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='BL-remove'!$A$24:$A$4523"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='BL-remove'!$K$24:$K$4523"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph 3").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='BL-remove'!$E$23"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='BL-remove'!$A$24:$A$4523"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='BL-remove'!$E$24:$E$4523"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph 4").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='BL-remove'!$B$23"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='BL-remove'!$A$24:$A$4523"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='BL-remove'!$B$24:$B$4523"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph 5").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='BL-remove'!$U$23"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='BL-remove'!$A$24:$A$4523"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='BL-remove'!$U$24:$U$4523"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph 6").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='BL-remove'!$AB$23"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='BL-remove'!$A$24:$A$4523"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='BL-remove'!$AB$24:$AB$4523"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph 7").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='BL-remove'!$I$23"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='BL-remove'!$A$24:$A$4523"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='BL-remove'!$I$24:$I$4523"
'...
```

I can't use a for-loop since the values associated to the graphs are not in order (i.e. Graph 1 values are not in A, Graph 2 values are not in B). I worked with Python in the past and used dictionaries, but I don't know how to do it with VBA.

I tried:

```vb
Dim Graph As Variant
Dim StringGraph As String

StringGraph = CStr(Graph)

Dim dic As Object
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dic.Add "1", "L"
dic.Add "2", "K"
dic.Add "3", "E"
dic.Add "4", "B"
dic.Add "5", "U"
dic.Add "6", "AB"
dic.Add "7", "I"

For Each Graph In dic.Keys
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph" & StringGraph).Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='BL-remove'!$ & dict(Graph) & $23"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='BL-remove'!$A$24:$A$4523"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='BL-remove'! _
      dict(Graph) & $24: $ dict(Graph)& $4523"
Next Graph
```

I know that I'm close the the answer, but maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
    Dim Graph As Variant
    Dim dic As Object, col As String
    
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.Add "1", "L"
    dic.Add "2", "K"
    dic.Add "3", "E"
    dic.Add "4", "B"
    dic.Add "5", "U"
    dic.Add "6", "AB"
    dic.Add "7", "I"
    
    For Each Graph In dic.Keys
        col = dic(Graph)
        With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph" & Graph).Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
            .Name = "='BL-remove'!$" & col & "$23"
            .XValues = "='BL-remove'!$A$24:$A$4523"
            .Values = "='BL-remove'!" & col & "$24:$" & col & "$4523"
        End With
    Next Graph
```

Comment: Your code is really excellent! You make my day, thank you!